# Emacs 27 MELPA connection failure on macOS

Tags: package-repositories

I have been trying to install packages `ivy`, `counsel`, and `swiper` on Emacs 27 prelude. Starting Emacs results in the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el’:

error: Could not create connection to melpa.org:443

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Any ideas on why startup fails?

I was using the following init file as a reference point: https://github.com/sitesonix/emacs-prelude-personal/blob/26dab880d0d096a1f04e81b9ee6ba470563aef8f/rtg-init.el.

Comment: I am able to ping and curl  melpa.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing newer Emacsen via Homebrew, use the `gnutls` switch:

```
brew reinstall emacs --HEAD --with-gnutls
```

Source: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-12/msg00439.html

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answers.

Comment: Just wanted to add that one can also install gnutls without reinstalling emacs. For example via `sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin`

Answer (score 3):

You may have to just use `http` instead of `https`

Here is what I have (essentially removed the `s` from `https`)

Not the perfect solution but something to get me going.

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
 (add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
;; (add-to-list 'package-archives
;;       '("melpa3" . "http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
;; Package.el stuff
```